# jQuery validation has stopped working with Zurb Foundation

Tags: jquery, validation, zurb-foundation

I have a form, it seemed to work, and validated well enough.  Now it doesn't seem to, and I can't figure out why not.  Mainly because I'm no expert.

I've used Zurb Foundation to create the site, and all things seem to be well with the rest of it, but if I could get some jQuery validation that would be epic.

Does anyone know where to start, or where to start to help other help me?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details than this.  We need to see the code (HTML, javascript) in as simplified a form as possible that demonstrates your issue.  Check out http://sscce.org/ for details on what that should look like.

Answer (score 1):

This is a conflict between Placeholder.js & validation.js

See this issue on GitHub
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/747